# Frame by frame animation that stops in between looping through images

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I learned how to run a frame by frame animation through a tutorial online, but I want my animation to run, then stop for 5 seconds, then run again.

Context: It's the opening screen of a game, and there's a cat in the background. I want his tail to wag once every 5 seconds or so. I can get the tail to wag endlessly, but don't know how to add in some kind of break.

```
func animateCatTailWagging() {
    catImage1 = UIImage(named: "gacha_title_cat_01")
    catImage2 = UIImage(named: "gacha_title_cat_02")
    catImage3 = UIImage(named: "gacha_title_cat_03")
    catImage4 = UIImage(named: "gacha_title_cat_04")
    catImage5 = UIImage(named: "gacha_title_cat_05")
    catImage6 = UIImage(named: "gacha_title_cat_06")
    catImage7 = UIImage(named: "gacha_title_cat_07")

    catImages = [catImage1, catImage2, catImage3, catImage4, catImage5, catImage6]

    animatedCatImage = UIImage.animatedImage(with: catImages, duration: 1.0)
    catImage.image = animatedCatImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `catImage6` five more times to the end of the array.

```
catImages = [catImage1, catImage2, catImage3, catImage4, catImage5, catImage6, catImage6, catImage6, catImage6, catImage6, catImage6]
```